# Unable to parse atom feed

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, atom-feed

I am implementing Youtube push notification and implemented webhook. Youtube gives updates in the form of atom feed. My problem is i can't parse that feed.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015">
<link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com" />
<link rel="self" href="https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCaNoTnXcQQt3ody_cLZSihw" />
<title>YouTube video feed</title>
<updated>2018-03-01T07:21:59.144766801+00:00</updated>
<entry>
    <id>yt:video:vNQyYJqFopE</id>
    <yt:videoId>vNQyYJqFopE</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>UCaNoTnXcQQt3ody_cLZSihw</yt:channelId>
    <title>Test Video 4</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNQyYJqFopE" />
    <author>
        <name>Testing</name>
        <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaNoTnXcQQt3ody_cLZSihw</uri>
    </author>
    <published>2018-03-01T07:21:48+00:00</published>
    <updated>2018-03-01T07:21:59.144766801+00:00</updated>
</entry>
```

```
 <?php
   $xml = '<?xml versio......';
   $obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
   echo '<pre>';print_r($obj);echo '</pre>';
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdbMG.png)

How to get the value of yt:videoId element. I am new to PHP, if I did anything wrong please correct me.

Comment: Please add the code for *"How to get the value of yt:videoId element"* that your tried.

Comment: I can't see that property in the output.That element contains `:`.

Comment: Did you try `$obj->entry->id`?

Comment: No, let me try.

Comment: Yes, i am getting. But i need the value of `yt:videoId`

Comment: It seems the XML elements containing the yt namespace (e.g. `<yt:videoId>`) are not being parsed by `simplexml_load_string`. I don't know why but in your case the video id is also present in the `<id>` element you just need to extract the last value or simply cut of `yt:video:` in front of it. That is at least an easy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the XML elements containing the yt namespace (e.g. `<yt:videoId>`) are not being parsed by `simplexml_load_string`. I don't know why but in your case the video id is also present in the `<id>` element you just need to extract the last value or simply cut of `yt:video:` in front of it. That is at least an easy workaround.

Also it works if you use a direct [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to the `<yt:videoId>` element like this:

```
echo $obj->xpath('//yt:videoId')[0];
// output: vNQyYJqFopE
```

XPath always returns an array so you need to get the first element with `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (updated)

```
$str = $obj->entry->id;
echo substr($str, strpos($str, "video:")+ 6);
```

Get the channel

```
$chan = $obj->entry->author->uri;
echo substr($chan , strpos($chan , "channel/")+ 8);
```

Comment: I want value of `yt:videoId` and it's value is vNQyYJqFopE and value of yt:channelId and it's value is `UCaNoTnXcQQt3ody_cLZSihw`